# Grant Identities permission only to a Particular sharepoint drive/document library and not at the site level

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am handling SharePoint granular permission using the sites.Selected the scope option and granted the application access/role via graph API permission. It is working fine, If the app needs to work with all the available Lists/Drives with the site.

For ex. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-Id}/Permissions` and passing the below payload.

```
{
    "roles": [
        "write"
    ],
    "grantedToIdentitiesV2": [
        {
            "application": {
                "id": << App Id >>
                "displayName": "TestDaemonGraphAPI"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I have a couple of drive/document libraries where the access needs to be restricted for the App.  Since I am setting permission at the site level, it allows access to all the drives.

How can we allow access at only Drive/library level using graph api?

Update: I've tried granting permission at the Drive level, it was failing.
[Error Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peMHV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you can restrict which Site collections or drives  can be accessed, first give `Sites.Seletced` permissions which restricts for only sites as you have already set.

[image]

Get all the ID of drive and select the Drive Id of the drives or document library that you want to restrict access to:

GET **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives`**

[image]

Then create a role specific to drive , and select only app that can have access to

POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/permissions`

```
{
    "roles": ["write"],
    "grantedToIdentitiesV2": [
        {
            "application": {
                "id": "{appid}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then delete the site permissions

`DELETE` `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/permissions/{permission-id}`

Check if this will restrict access to only that particular drive. I couldn't check this as I  can't access as office365 license is needed.

**Reference:**

[Controlling app access on a specific SharePoint site collections is now available in Microsoft Graph - Microsoft 365 Developer Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/)

or

You can check this way of breaking permissions with unique permissions by inviting only few users [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

Comment: I've tried this earlier.  I am getting the below error while setting permission at the drive level. POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/permissions 
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'permissions'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-02-24T16:40:28",
            "request-id": "89b36721-e774-4310-8303-85f8bc06481c",
            "client-request-id": "8608f3eb-bf53-da65-f114-0e4c64de89b0"
        }
    }
}

Comment: okay,Have you got to check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

Comment: Thanks, Kavya. Let me verify whether this works with the Managed identity/app Id